# Why does FileHelpers require FieldOptional even after FieldInNewLine?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a FileHelpers-record with a property marked as `[FieldOptional]`.
I appreciate that this might require the rest of the properties of the line to be optional.
Although it might still be possible to parse the rest of the line, it may get harder.

But if my next property is marked as `[FieldInNewLine]`, FileHelpers still want it to be `[FieldOptional]`.
However I think it would be easy (possibly easier) to not require for this property (and the next) be optional.

So with this code

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
public class SomeRecord
{
    [FieldFixedLength(10)][FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string S1;
    [FieldOptional][FieldFixedLength(10)][FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string S2;
    [FieldInNewLine][FieldFixedLength(10)][FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string S3;
}
```

I get a `FileHelpers.BadUsageException` message

> The field: S2 must be marked as optional because the previous field is marked as optional. (Try adding [FieldOptional] to S2)

Does anybody know a reason, why this is required?
(althoug the code is no real code, the Exception-message does erroneously refer to the wrong property, I did not make that up.)

PS: I use 2.9.9.0 from NuGet

Comment: If the actual record has a missing S2 string but the S3 string is present, how could it know that it isn't the S2 string?  If you know the answer then just modify the source code for the library.

Comment: Because S3 starts on a new line as defined by `[FieldInNewLine]`, and S2 should not start on a new line. (I wonder if I would be able to modify the library, I don't know how complicated it is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the code checks only if the previous field was optional that the current field also be optional https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers/Core/RecordInfo.cs#L316

A suggested code change on that line might be

```
if (prevField.IsOptional && currentField.IsOptional == false && 
    !currentField.InNewLine)
```

Also it looks like they're passing the previous field to the error message, when it should be the current field name, so you can fix that too

```
throw new BadUsageException(Messages.Errors.ExpectingFieldOptional
                                    .FieldName(currentField.FieldInfo.Name)
                                    .Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for locating the _where_, which may incidentally be the _why_.  I hope I find the time soon, to check the code out, and see if it parses correctly after removing the check.  If it does not, the check might also be built in for a reason :-) .

Comment: Changes Merged in the master repo :)